# Remove the first white space from specified column in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, trim

Let's create an imaginary table named `music` which has the columns `id`, `artist` and `title`.

The first 2 `rows` will be:

```
1|C. Dione|My heart will go one;
2| C. Dione|I drive all night;
```

Now apparently both of data are correctly, but if We will use them into an `jquery autocomplete` using `SELECT DISTINCT(artist)` will give as 2 artists

```
C. Dione
```

and

```
 C. Dione
```

How to remove the first white space in the `artist` column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LTRIM(artist)) ....
```

Or you could also do,

```
UPDATE music set artist = LTRIM(artist)
```

which will prevent you from doing LTRIM everytime in the SELECT

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table set column= LTRIM(column);
```